# Difference between Bogoliubov-Shirkov renormalization group and Wilson's Renormalization group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, definition, renormalization, effective-field-theory

I just learned the Wilsonian renormalization group from a QFT lecture, I heard that there is another renormalization group called Bogoliubov-Shirkov renormalization group which is a true group instead of a semi-group in the case of Wilsonian RG. My question is what is Bogoliubov-Shirkov RG? What is the most important difference between these two RG? In their application, which one is better or more powerful?

Comment: I have never heard of it, but after some digging, the paper that sparked the (so called)  Bogoliubov-Shirkov RG is here: [original paper from 1956](https://inspirehep.net/literature/42641). In the paper, Bogoliubov pointed out that Gell-Mann and Low (apparently) did some of their calculations wrong for their RG flow which came out in 1954. But, you can actually find a YouTube video of Gell-Mann saying their work was apparently copied word for word (I can link it if need be). But any search for their particular flow I can't find (I can only find history of RG).

Comment: So as far as I can tell, there is no functional difference. But besides that, this type of RG flow was surpassed by Wilson-Polchinski flow which is much more commonly used anyways.